# Semantically confusing webwork question Calculus 2

Tags: integration, volume

Using disks or washers, find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the curves $y=\sqrt{x-1}$, $y=0$, $x=2$, and $x=3$ about the $x$-axis.

To me it seems like this question is asking for the upper half of the solid because it specifies $y=0$.

Setting it up, then: $\dfrac{\pi}{2}\displaystyle\int_{2}^{3}\left(\sqrt{x-1}\right)^2dx$ and the answer is $3\pi/4$.

That is not the answer webwork is after, though.

What don't I understand about how $y=0$ figures in?

TIA

Comment: Why have you divided your $pi$ upfront the integral by $2$? This is a classic disc problem.The $y=0$ ensures this is just a disc problem, otherwise it could have been a washer problem.

Comment: It already says the x axis. So why state it twice unless it adds some information?

Comment: The $x$-axis is your axis of revolution. $y = 0$ is how you bound the region that you're revolving. They're two separate things.

Comment: Well, it's happy with that, so must be. Normally you don't include another function unless it modifies r, however.

Answer (score 3):

The question is not asking for just the upper half as it's of the solid rotated *completely* around the $x$-axis. Note that to rotate a region with certain bounds around the $x$-axis, you need to know what those bounds are. In this case, the lower vertical bound is specified as being $y = 0$.

However, as [imranfat](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/64546/imranfat)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3563882/semantically-confusing-webwork-question-calculus-2/3563884#comment7328115_3563882) indicates, if this lower limit was replaced by something else, say like $y = 1$ instead, you would still rotate it completely around the $x$-axis. However, because the rotation region is smaller, the resulting volume would be smaller as well. Also, because the lower bound would then no longer coincide with the line you're rotating around, i.e., the $x$-axis which is the same as $y = 0$, it would change from being a disc problem to being a washer problem instead.

Note the disc method to determine volume rotations is a special of the washer method, where the internal circle is a degenerate one with a radius of $0$. Thus, your current volume is double what your integral specifies, but with the lower bound squared being implicitly subtracted, i.e., it would be $\pi\int_{2}^{3}\left((\sqrt{x-1})^2 - (0)^2\right)dx$. Also, in my alternate example above of a lower bound of $y = 1$, the integral would instead be $\pi\int_{2}^{3}\left((\sqrt{x-1})^2 - (1)^2\right)dx$.

A more general different case would be if the lower bound of the region was $y = -1$ and rotating around the line $y = -2$. In this case, the region being rotated would include parts of both the upper & lower halves of the Cartesian co-ordinate plane being rotated. Also, since the height of the function would then be $\sqrt{x - 1} - (-2) = \sqrt{x - 1} + 2$, but with the height still being $-1 - (-2) = 1$ for the lower bound, the volume in this case would then be given by $\pi\int_{2}^{3}\left((\sqrt{x-1} + 2)^2 - (1)^2\right)dx$.

Comment: Well, I was assuming that it specified y=0 for some reason. y=0 is the x axis, so saying it again must mean the volume that strictly lies between this curve and the x axis, not further.

Maybe I am trying to make something sensible that is just redundant, though.

Comment: @mtlchk As KM101 stated, the lower bound of $y = 0$ and rotating around the $x$-axis are separate things, with them just happening to coincide. It also helps to make your work a bit easier. I added some more details about this in my answer, including about a more general different case. I hope this helps you to better understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $y=0$ is the equation of the $x$-axis in the rectangular Cartesian plane.

Thus, the question is just telling you to calculate the area of the region between the given parabola, the vertical lines and the horizontal line that happens to be the $x$-axis.